# Understanding .obj file

Tags: 3d-meshes, file-format, file, jmonkeyengine, obj

I downloaded a 3d model of a car. By judging by the skins and images available model treats wheels and car body as separate nodes. I want to access its child nodes (wheels) to specify animation.

But I don't know the names of its child nodes. Is it possible to figure out names of its child nodes by looking at the file content. I have a obj file of the 3D model. 
I am using JMonkey 2.

**EDIT** 
here is the link [thefree3dmodels](http://thefree3dmodels.com/stuff/vehicles/ford_crown_victoria/13-1-0-769).

Thank you in advance

Comment: For the record, .obj is a pretty common file extension, you should first of all find out which of the different formats you are dealing with.

Comment: It is a Wavefront file, the groups of this file have numerical names 000 through 037.

Comment: @eBusiness Can you tell me how to access them.(I prefer JMonkey). That model is a Trimesh. Is there a way to identify which number refers which mesh. In this case group id of a wheel?

Comment: I can't tell, and I don't know JMonkey. Though I'm not certain that there is an easy way of doing what you want, it's only the triangles that are grouped, not the vertices, and you'd animate a model by moving the vertices. But then again, I'm not an expert 3D programmer, I can't say for sure that there isn't some trick.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [obj file specification](http://www.martinreddy.net/gfx/3d/OBJ.spec) it should be a string after the 'g' command, but from my experiences each obj exporter handles those things specifically.

It might help to add link to obj file in your first post.

**EDIT**

According to the model file, those wheels are groups with numbers 13, 14, 24, 25 Proof:

[image]

So those faces (and according vertexes, normals and textures) after line `g part 013` to the next line with `g` command is the mesh of the wheel and so on..

I'm not using JMonkey so I don't precisely know how to rotate those parts, but you could cut the car mesh into two files (wheels and rest) and then it should be easy to animate..

Comment: I added the link. how can I access the groups to apply some texture or to animate them?